# How does one generate epub/mobi eBooks from LaTeX?

Tags: html, ebook

I can think of a couple of ways:

1. PlasTeX + manual .epub manipulations. See: 
   [Is there a PlasTeX custom-renderer which can produce ePub (or nearly ePub)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15078/is-there-a-plastex-custom-renderer-which-can-produce-epub-or-nearly-epub) 
   @salimfadhley Did you end up going this way?
2. tex4ht / latex2html / etc. See: 
   [LaTeX document to epub or mobi ebook formats (with mathematical formulas)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16569/latex-document-to-epub-or-mobi-ebook-formats-with-mathematical-formulas)
3. MathJax rendering on `.epub` devices which run js. But what about the fonts?

I am not sure which way to go though and I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Have you seen this (duplicate): [Use LaTeX to produce Epub](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1551/5764)

Comment: I haven't read this [article](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2012-1/luca.html) but it may be of interest.