# How to remove LaTeX control sequences from a .tex document using plasTeX?

Tags: macros, programming, html, python, scripts

I need to get just the text and math expressions (ignoring tables, pictures and styling) from a set of LaTeX documents and represent them in html.

Looks like plasTeX and MathJaX are enough for this task.

As I understand, after plasTeX has parsed the document, I would need to get all text nodes of the document and all nodes with math. For the math nodes I would try to preserve their LaTeX source. Is it possible, using plasTeX, to get LaTeX source of a math expression with all the commands already applied?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Do you want everything removed which is inside a command or an environment, or is it just for some specific commands/environments (tables, etc)?

Comment: Thanks! I want to get all math expressions from LaTeX document, and if the author created some new commands/environments in the document, I want to get them unfolded.

Comment: @masu , for example (the example is taken from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros), if if a have in the document these lines 
\newcommand{\wbal}{The Wikibook about \LaTeX}
This is ‘‘\wbal'' \ldots{} ‘‘\wbal''
I want to get them as just:
This is ‘‘The Wikibook about \LaTeX''.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is. Run Plastex with theme:minimal.

See answer to question:
[Is there a PlasTeX custom-renderer which can produce ePub (or nearly ePub)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15078/is-there-a-plastex-custom-renderer-which-can-produce-epub-or-nearly-epub)

Comment: Can you expand on this for the particular situation here?  Otherwise this is just a comment.

Comment: This should be fleshed out with a MWE showing the solution to the OP's question. Since it is the only answer, this is particularly important.